# Can't find error in my json and javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I am making a food ordering system.Now I have to make a cart page in such a way that the item gets added to it as soon as I click on it.I have made a json file containing all the items and a js file that runs it.I am not getting any error but the output is not coming
Here is my json code:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Lasagna",
    "picture": "images/lasagna.jpg",
    "price": 500
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mexican Pizza",
    "picture": "images/mpizza.jpg",
    "price": 310
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Tiramisu Shake",
    "picture": "images/tiramisu.jpg",
    "price": 290
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Penne Pasta",
    "picture": "images/ppizza.jpg",
    "price": 280
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Classic Maggi",
    "picture": "images/maggi.jpg",
    "price": 120
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Nachos",
    "picture": "images/nachos.jpg",
    "price": 250
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Margarita Pizza",
    "picture": "images/margarita.jpg",
    "price": 220
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Kitkat Shake",
    "picture": "images/kitkat.jpg",
    "price": 310
  },
  
]
```

And here is my js code:

```
$.getJSON('food.json', function(data) {
  var foodRow = $('#foodRow');
  var foodTemplate = $('#foodTemplate');

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
    foodTemplate.find('.panel-title').text(data[i].name);
    foodTemplate.find('img').attr('src', data[i].picture);
    foodTemplate.find('.price').text(data[i].price);
    foodTemplate.find('.btn-success').attr('data-id', data[i].id);
    console.log(data[i].id)
    foodRow.append(foodTemplate.html());
  }
});

$("button").click(function(){
  var i = $(this).attr("data-id");
  console.log(i);
  ('$out').text(i)
});
```

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Foodzie</title>
  <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/887e6e97bd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- CSS STYLESHEET -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- FONTS -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&family=Ubuntu:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script src="food.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
<body>

  <section id="title">

    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <div class="fluid-container">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">FoodZie</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">View Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Add Items</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
       </div>
      </nav>

    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="fluid-container">

  <div id="foodRow" class="row">
        <!-- PETS LOAD HERE -->
  </div>

<div id="foodTemplate" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-pet">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <br>
        <h3 class="panel-title">Pizza</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <img alt="140x140" data-src="holder.js/140x140" class="img-rounded img-center" style="width: 100%;" src="images/mpizza.jpg" data-holder-rendered="true" height="140" width="140">
        <br/><br/>
        <strong>Cost</strong>: <span class="price">250</span><br/><br/>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" data-id="0" id = "cart">Add to Cart</button><br>
        <p id=out></p>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Add your html code as well for more understanding

Comment: what is `('$out').text(i)` ? it shouldn't be `$('$out').text(i)` ?

Comment: does this `console.log(data[i].id)` gets printed in browser console ?

Comment: your question is unclear, where do you want to " gets added to it as soon as I click on it."? do you want to add it to your current food.json? or just display in .out container?

"output is not coming" do you mean the data is not successfuly stored in the json?

Comment: Added my html code

Comment: @Swati No no output is printing in console

Comment: @rickvian Display the container

Comment: See what I wanted to do is when we click on add to cart button,the button id should get registered which is displayed on cart page.But the button id's attribute is unable to find

Comment: Not sure if this was added by accident in your question but there is an extra space in your loop (i = 0; i < data.length; i ++)  - should be i++

Comment: Did that worked for you ? Have corrected all the errors I have highlighted below.

Comment: Yes that worked! Thankyou so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few issues in your current `code`. You have extra `,` in your `JSON` file which is **silently** throws an error but it will not show up in the console.

Secondly, you are not displaying the `data-id` of the add to `cart` button correctly your `syntax` is incorrect.

```
$('#out').text(i)
```

Also, you are adding your products dynamically after the `DOM` is loaded so you need to use `event Delegation` in this case to attach events to your `Add to Cart` buttons.

```
$(document).on('click', '.cart', function(){
  var i = $(this).data("id"); //get the data-id of the clicked button
  console.log(i);
  $('#out').text(i)
});
```

Please note i am also using a `class` selector in your Add to Cart `<button class="btn btn-success cart" type="button" data-id="0">Add to Cart</button><br>` button - `id's` must be unique for each button to avoid issues.

**Complete working code:**

```js
//Food JSON file
var data = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Lasagna",
    "picture": "images/lasagna.jpg",
    "price": 500
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mexican Pizza",
    "picture": "images/mpizza.jpg",
    "price": 310
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Tiramisu Shake",
    "picture": "images/tiramisu.jpg",
    "price": 290
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Penne Pasta",
    "picture": "images/ppizza.jpg",
    "price": 280
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Classic Maggi",
    "picture": "images/maggi.jpg",
    "price": 120
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Nachos",
    "picture": "images/nachos.jpg",
    "price": 250
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Margarita Pizza",
    "picture": "images/margarita.jpg",
    "price": 220
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Kitkat Shake",
    "picture": "images/kitkat.jpg",
    "price": 310
  }
]

//$.getJSON('food.json', function(data) { //un comment this in your code
  var foodRow = $('#foodRow');
  var foodTemplate = $('#foodTemplate');

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
    foodTemplate.find('.panel-title').text(data[i].name);
    foodTemplate.find('img').attr('src', data[i].picture);
    foodTemplate.find('.price').text(data[i].price);
    foodTemplate.find('.btn-success').attr('data-id', data[i].id);
    //console.log(data[i].id)
    foodRow.append(foodTemplate.html());
  }
//});

//Click event
$(document).on('click', '.cart', function(){
  var i = $(this).data("id");
  console.log(i);
  $('#out').text(i)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Foodzie</title>
  <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/887e6e97bd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <section id="title">

    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <div class="fluid-container">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">FoodZie</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">View Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Add Items</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
       </div>
      </nav>

    </div>
  </section>

  <div class="fluid-container">

  <div id="foodRow" class="row">
        <!-- PETS LOAD HERE -->
  </div>

<div id="foodTemplate">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-pet">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <br>
        <h3 class="panel-title">Pizza</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <img alt="140x140" data-src="holder.js/140x140" class="img-rounded img-center" style="width: 100%;" src="images/mpizza.jpg" data-holder-rendered="true" height="140" width="140">
        <br/><br/>
        <strong>Cost</strong>: <span class="price">250</span><br/><br/>
        <button class="btn btn-success cart" type="button" data-id="0">Add to Cart</button><br>
        <p id='out'></p>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```